# Como fazer um select distinct na função ListAGG no banco 12C

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Existe alguma função do banco 12c que consiga usar no `listagg` e não traga resultados repetidos?

```
SELECT SUM(quantidade) quantidade,
      LISTAGG (mib.segment1, ' - ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) item,
      LISTAGG (mib.description, ' - ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ROWNUM) descricao                  
 FROM xg_tab_om_pedido_pneus a, 
      xg_tab_om_dpn_pedidos b,
      xg_tab_om_dpns cc,
      mtl_system_items_b mib
WHERE a.id_dpn_pedido = b.id_dpn_pedido
  AND b.id_dpn = cc.id_dpn
  AND mib.inventory_item_id = a.inventory_item_id
  AND mib.organization_id = c.ship_from_org_id
```

Essa consulta me retorna itens repetidos, eu gostaria o retorno fosse valor único.

Answer (score -1):

Cara acredito que não, o que você pode fazer é um `wm_concat(distinct mib.segment1)` e depois dar um replace na , por -, dentro pro listagg nunca consegui usar distinct